# New php user--trying to open .php file in test environment

Tags: php

Using mac OS, installed MAMP. Everything seems to be running fine. Created a PHP file in the htdocs folder, tried to open it with Firefox but won't recognize PHP file. Asks me which program I want to use to open the file, when I choose firefox, blank screen comes up.

Comment: What is the content of that php file? What coding you have done in that file?

Comment: You need to run the PHP from your local web-server. Also, show your code

Answer (score 0):

Open it by typing in your browser `localhost/path/to/your/file.php` and MAMP (assuming everything is in fact working) will then parse the file and return the output from the request.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac & MAMP, the path in the address bar should be:

`http://localhost:8888/folder_name/your_page_name.php`

Also, this will help you configure MAMP appropriately

http://sawmac.com/mamp/

Answer (score 0):

inspite of all bad configuration of mamp,opening file with firefox must show something written over it,so please show code u wrote there as said by Dan and  DarkXphenomenon